# Neo4j query with Boolean operations between Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql, boolean-operations

We have a graph DB with nodes: Resume and Skill.
Skill node contains property - "Name". It has sample Values like Java, C ...

And we created relationship has_skill between Resume and Skill Nodes. And each Resume node can contain any number of Skill nodes with relationship has_skill.

Now, we want to retrieve all resume nodes which satisfies following boolean condition.

```
((JAVA AND MYSQL) OR (C AND MSSQL)) AND HTML
```

We have tried the following query

```
match(n:Skill)--(n1:PannaResume)
where ((n.name contains "java" AND n.name contains "mysql")
OR (n.name contains "c" AND n.name contains "mssql")) 
AND n.name contains "html"
return n1
```

But this is not giving the expected result. Please suggest correct query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're query is failing because you are asking Neo4j to find a person, who has a skill, that is at least 3 skills simultaneously. Obviously, given skill n, it will never be java and mysql and html. (I assume you are using contains to 'strip' any version information they may have added to the skill name, like javaee or java 8. Just remember this will also match javascript. I would recommend however you are getting this data into Neo4j, to have it parse the general name out to a separate field. If you are treating name as a skill array, then you probably have no matches, and your scheme is too fragile to do anything useful with)

I would recommend this match pattern so that Neo4j checks for any valid skill node

```
MATCH (n:Skill)<--(n1:PannaResume)
WITH n1, COLLECT(n.name) as skills
WHERE ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "html")
AND (ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "java")
 OR ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "mysql")
)
OR (
(ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "c")
 OR ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "mssql")
))
```

of course, more explicit is better. This will perform much better.

```
MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
WHERE ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "java"}) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mysql"}))
OR ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "c"}) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mssql"}))
RETURN n1
```

But you can also simplify a bit (and make it easier on the Cypher planner) by separating your query into a set of distinct queries, and union the results like this

```
MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
WHERE (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "java"}) 
  AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mysql"})
RETURN n1
UNION
MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
WHERE (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "c"})
  AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mssql"})
RETURN n1
```

This should be equivalent to the previous queries, but may be more efficient depending on what you are doing/Neo4j version. The WITH will break the query into different stages, so will force the Cypher planner to find the skill nodes first, and then find a person connected to those skills.

```
MATCH (html:Skill {name : "html"}), (java:Skill {name : "java"}), (c:Skill {name : "c"}), (mysql:Skill {name : "mysql"}), (mssql:Skill {name : "mssql"})
WITH *
MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(html)
WHERE ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(java) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(mysql)
OR ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(c) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(mssql)
RETURN n1
```

If you need to worry about efficiency, you should experiment with different quires using the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) keyword. The key thing you are trying to do is minimize how many rows each 'stage' of the query produces, as every stage after that will be multiplied by the number of rows the previous stage produced. (The Cypher planner can choose to perform multiple queries in parallel, and then find the intersection of them. So it's not obvious how alteration to a Cypher will affect the plan. PROFILE will show you inefficiencies in your query, so take note of steps with high dbhits or result in a lot of rows.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both of the mentioned queries, the first Query did 2932334 db hits with 3s of time and the 2nd query did 5839613 total db hits with 2s of time. And both of them doing NodeByLabelScans. Are these queries scalable and performance effective?

Comment: @SarathBabu You should create an index on :Skill(name) for faster lookup, you want to see index seeks in the plan, not nodebylabelscans.

Comment: @SarathBabu No. You are taking every person, and multiplying it (at least) by every skill in your database. I updated 2 so that it only takes every person who knows HTML and multiply that against the skills database. I also added a 3'rd one that shows off using Union. In this instance, this may be faster. (Also as Falcon said, Index or better Unique Constraint (is also an index) on Skill.name would tremendously help Neo4j find the skill associations, as it will be able to just pull up the 5 skills using that, and then do the rest of the logic)

Comment: @Tezra, I got you and thanks for your response. Now we have tried 3 different ways to address my problem and attaching below the all 3 solution details with query and total DB hits that each one took. Now we are looking for suggestion on scalable & performance effective solution out of these 3 solutions.

Comment: Solution1: 
 Convert all Skill node data into a String with comma separated and add it as a property under PannaResume node.
  match (n1:PannaResume)--(p:Skill)  with n1,collect (p.name) as x with reduce(s=head(x),n in tail(x) | s+','+n) as result,n1 match (n1) set n1.skillName=result return n1.skillName
 Then did Query using below
  match (n1:PannaResume)--(p:Skill)  where ((n1.skillName contains "java" OR n1.skillName contains "c") AND (n1.skillName contains "mysql" OR n1.skillName contains "oracle")) return distinct(n1)
 Result: 1596247 DB Hits in 1462ms

Comment: Solution2: 
 Convert all Skill node data into List and add it under PannaResume node.
  match (n1:PannaResume)--(p:Skill)  with collect (p.name) as x ,n1 match (n1) set n1.skillList=x return n1.skillList
 Then did Query using below
  PROFILE match (n1:PannaResume)--(p:Skill)  where (("java" in n1.skillList OR "c" in n1.skillList) AND ("mysql" in n1.skillList OR "oracle" in n1.skillList)) return distinct(n1)
 Result: 1685902 DB Hits in 2026ms

Comment: Solution3: (Suggested by you)
 MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
 WHERE (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "java"}) 
   AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mysql"})
 RETURN n1
 UNION
 MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
 WHERE (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "c"})
   AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mssql"})
 RETURN n1

 Result: 5839613 DB Hits in 2014ms

Comment: @SarathBabu Is that with [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-unique-nodes) applied to Skill.name? And how many people nodes are there? (and how many valid returns?) It should not take Cypher 5m DB hits to pull up 5 nodes and find a common link as long as those nodes are properly indexed. The syntax would be `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Skill) ASSERT s.name IS UNIQUE`

Comment: Without the Unique Constraint, Cypher will do an inefficient plan, fearing that doing it the right way will actually explode the results and crash with out-of-memory. So instead, it will repeatedly do a scan-by-label on each skill check to try and save memory. (Without the Unique constraint, or at least an index, Cypher has to assume all Skill nodes my correctly match, and will plan accordingly)

Comment: @Tezra We have 92K Person nodes and 6K Skill nodes
After applying Unique index, still it took 2913877 DB hits for 

MATCH (n:Skill)<--(n1:PannaResume)
WITH n1, COLLECT(n.name) as skills
WHERE ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "html")
AND (ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "java")
 OR ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "mysql")
)
OR (
(ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "c")
 OR ANY(name in skills WHERE name contains "mssql")
)) return n1

Comment: @SarathBabu What about the other 2? The Unique constraint doesn't help the first query. The first query assumes no index, and the number of Skill nodes isn't too many, So it asks Cypher to load all Skill.name into memory, and then do a couple checks to see if certain values are in that list. That is only 'efficient' if the db has no better way of finding things. It will degrade with every additional skill and skill check. The other 2 don't have that problem as long as they are indexed. (Unique Constraint also adds the index for that property)

Comment: @Tezra, Below one had 2139609 DB Hits .                                                     MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
WHERE ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "java"}) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mysql"}))
OR ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "c"}) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mssql"}))
RETURN n1

Comment: And the last query had 2156052 DB hits.      MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
WHERE (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "java"}) 
  AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mysql"})
RETURN n1
UNION
MATCH (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "html"})
WHERE (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "c"})
  AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mssql"})
RETURN n1

Comment: @Tezra, If we convert Skill node data into as a property (Either comma separated String or List) under Person node, then we noticed the DB hits were only about 15L to 16L (Mentioned in my Solution1 & Solution2). So will those be the optimal solutions in our specific use case? Also if we decide convert data from Node to property, is there any other impacts for long run maintenance and performances.

Comment: @SarathBabu I added one more query to my answer that may be more efficient. If you could run PROFILE on the query, and share the result, it would be a lot easier to tell what Cypher is doing wrong, and how to 'fix' the query.  The problem with using properties instead of nodes, is it becomes harder to match patterns. For example, JavaSE and JavaEE are both Java, but JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. So the node representation will allow you to specify aliases, or skill groups (like OOP languages vs Query languages). So not using nodes will make it difficult to use those relationships.

Comment: @SarathBabu Neo4j is very effective at edge walking. With the Unique Constraint, it should be able to find people that way just fine. However, Cypher only says what you want back, not how to get it. The Cypher Planner decides how to find it based on what statistics it has to rely on. So sadly, different queries will perform differently on different data sets. The same Cypher can generate different Execution plans. (I was able to convert a DB killing query to a super optimal one by simply upgrading my Neo4j db to the latest version, that had a much smarter Cypher Planner)

Comment: @Tezra, New query had 1989837 DB hits, its quite good compared to earlier ones.

Comment: @Tezra . From application perspective as we have to support any combinations of boolean operations(AND/OR's). So we tried changing it to as below.Then it had 38L DB hits.   profile MATCH (html:Skill {name : "html"}), (java:Skill {name : "java"}), (c:Skill {name : "c"}), (mysql:Skill {name : "mysql"}), (mssql:Skill {name : "mssql"})
WITH *
MATCH (n1:PannaResume)
WHERE ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(java) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(mysql))
OR ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(c) AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(mssql))
AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(html)
RETURN n1

Comment: @Tezra, currently we are running your suggested queries in Neo4j Desktop version 3.1.12. And we are handling Alias names through application logic so we can ignore them from Neo4j query perspective.

Comment: @SarathBabu What do you mean by `38L`? Is that L as in the numeral 50? Also, one last tip, depending on your query, using `WITH DISTINCT` and `RETURN DISTINCT` may improve your results further. The DISTINCT hint adds a bit of overhead, but it also lets the Cypher planner know it can do more minimal work. This is usually needed when doing variable path length queries. I don't think it will help here, but doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: @Tezra, 38L I meant 38 Lakhs(exactly we noticed 3830870) DB hits. Also I used RETURN with DISTINCT, that didn't help any in this use case, same number of DB hits.

Comment: @SarathBabu alright. I don't think I can help you any further unless you add the profile results to the question (expand all nodes and save as image) That will tell me what part of the query it doesn't like.

Comment: @Tezra, thanks for your time and help. We are planning to go with converting Skill data into list and add it as property under Person node. Because so far it's the best and cleaner approach in terms of number of DB hits. Further we are planning to utilize cache mechanism to avoid the load on DB for duplicate hits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking by the pattern existence:

```
match (n1:PannaResume)-[:has_skill]->(n:Skill)
where ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "java"}) and (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mysql"}))
OR ((n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "c"}) and (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "mssql"}))
AND (n1)-[:has_skill]->(:Skill {name : "HTML"})
RETURN n1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. DB getting hanged when we run this query.